# Checking First Character of String Array

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method that will scan the first character of a user entered array and see if it is a vowel but I have a couple of questions. Here is the code I have so far:

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    String[] input= new String [5];
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your words...");
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        a[j]=scan.next();
    }

 }
```

1. Ignore the array size of 5. How would I make it possible for the user to add as many words as they would like? Should I add "Enter q when you are finished" and while (j != 'q'); ? What should I make the array size?
2. Would this work to check the first character of each array entered:

`if ((input[j].charAt(0)=='a')||(input[j].charAt(0)=='e')||(input[j].charAt(0)=='i')||              (input[j].charAt(0)=='o')||(input[j].charAt(0)=='u'))`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a List, not an array. The size of a list is dynamic. You could write the check for a vowel as you suggested. A regex would probably more elegant though, since you could aggregate all vowels in one statement, but your solution wors fine if yu experiment.

Comment: Regarding the second part of your question: try it, and see by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use an `ArrayList`.
2. Try it. Also consider using `startsWith()`.

Answer (score 1):

1. The simple answer is to use any `List` class; for example `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.
2. Hints:

   - what about capital letters?
   - What about characters with accents?
   - if you are going to use a complicated expression like that, consider using a temporary variable

Answer (score 0):

1: For the array, use an ArrayList, it has a dynamic size.

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
```

To add something to it:

```
input.add(scan.next());
```

2: Yes, that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Character> vowels = Arrays.asList('a','e','i','o','u');
if(vowels.contains(input[j].charAt(0))) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know a priori how many strings will be fed in input then the solution is to use a dynamic data structure, like a list:

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
input.add(scan.next());
```

Checking if a letter is a vowel is a typical thing which can be solved with an utility function to keep behavior separated:

```
boolean isVowel(char c) {
  switch (Character.toLowercase(c)) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
      return true;
    default: return false;
  }
}

boolean startsWithVowel = isVowel(input.get(0).charAt(0))
```

Comment: Did you import package `java.util.*`?